# Extension on Edge on IE compatibility mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm working on a browser extension, initially for Chromium browsers. The extension injects css and js files in the page, and modify content.
We have tried to install it on Edge. It's work fine in most of cases, but doesn't work when a web page is in IE11 compatibility mode. The extension does nothing.
Is it totally impossible to run an extension in the case of IE11 compatibility mode ?

Thanks.

Comment: From your comment, it seems that Robbi's answer has solved your issue. If so, you can mark the answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You should see what errors are generated in the DevTool window.
It is easy that some object \ method \ property called by the extension at the time of IE11 did not exist yet.

In any case if you take a look here   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode
you may read that extensions that interact directly with the page content are not supported.

Comment: The explanations on the docs link are what i was looking for. Thanks !